# Showing $\int_0^1\frac{\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{2x}{1+x^2}\right)}{1+x^2}dx=\frac{\pi^2}{16}$

Tags: calculus, integration

Could someone please explain how to arrive at this answer?

$$\int_0^1\frac{\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{2x}{1+x^2}\right)}{1+x^2}dx=\frac{\pi^2}{16}$$

I'm having trouble to approach this competition problem. I'm not sure if a clever $u$-substitution($u=1+x^2$?!), series approach (maybe the Basel problem?! because $\pi^2$!!), or some other form would be a suitable approach.

Comment: If anyone could help me LaTex the title. Thank you!

Comment: Trig substitution I reckon.

Comment: Oh smart! Lemme try that @TSF

Comment: $\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{2x}{1+x^2}\right) = 2\tan^{-1}x$

Answer (score 6):

Substitute $x=\tan\theta, dx=\sec^2\theta d\theta$ to get

$$\int_0^\frac\pi4\dfrac{\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{2\tan\theta}{1+\tan^2\theta}\right)\sec^2\theta d\theta}{1+\tan^2\theta}=\int_0^\frac\pi4\sin^{-1}\frac{2\tan\theta}{\sec^2\theta}d\theta=$$
$$\int_0^\frac\pi4\sin^{-1}(2\sin\theta\cos\theta) d\theta=\int_0^\frac\pi42\theta d\theta$$